# Example of Gorenstein ring that has infinite Krull dimension?

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, krull-dimension, gorenstein

Let $R$ be a Noetherian commutative ring. If $R$ is local, then $R$ is Gorenstein if $inj.dim(R)<\infty$. Otherwise $R$ is Gorenstein if $R_P$ Gorenstein for all prime ideals $P$.\

There is a simple result stating that $inj.dim(R)<\infty$ if and only if $R$ is Gorenstein and it has finite Krull dimension, and I proved it. My question is, is there any ring that is Gorenstein and has infinite Krull dimension?

Comment: What about the Nagata example of Noetherian ring with infinite Krull dimension?

Comment: Found it. I'll check

Comment: Since regular rings are Gorenstein, your question was answered [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/119627).

Comment: Interesting... Some machine classified my answer as "trivial" and hence converted it to a comment. Whatever. (But the machine has not seen that I wrote complete nonsense at first. Ha!)